# Javascript how to make text 10% larger

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website and it is nearly finished and while testing someone mentioned a setting for text size. Now I know I can just go through and make the font to a set value that is set by something else. But I want to see if I can do it with Javascript.

On my settings page I have a `range` input from 80% to 120%, but how it will work is it will make the text size bigger depending on the current value it is. For example, the size setting was set to 100%, then I increased it to 110% I want all text to get 10% bigger than before, but I don't have a clue on how to do it, even if it's possible. If anyone has a different method to changing font size based on a setting that would be useful.

Or can I do this:

```
font-size: {{setting}};
```

for the whole document after I have loaded the rest of the CSS, meaning would this set all text to this size or make it bigger/smaller depending on if its over 100%?

Comment: `.addEventListener("change", () => document.body.className = "fontsize-" + this.value)` + correspondent css classes

Comment: Don't forget that there is a font size setting in the browser too. Not to mention zoom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change all of the text elements font sizes to be a variable, like this:

```
:root {
    --base-size: 10px;
}
.paragraph-here {
    font-size: var(--base-size);
}
.heading-here {
    font-size: calc(2 * var(--base-size));
}
```

The `--base-size` variable could then be customized in an inline style in JavaScript.

Another option would be to add `zoom` to the entire page, like this:

```
body {
    zoom: 110%;
}
```

This would grow the entire page though, not just the text elements.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I like the `var()` approach, the `zoom` I definitely wouldn't recommend it

Comment: Do you modify `--base-size` on `document.documentElement.style` then?

Comment: While I haven't tested that, I think document.documentElement is the way to go. I personally have used document.body as well, and that works fine as well in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

The "right" way to set font sizes on elements is with 'rem' or 'em' units, never with fixed 'px' units.

If your document uses this method, then simply changing the body's font-size will change all the other element sizes.

```js
function resize (factor) {
  let sizeStr = document.body.style.fontSize;
  let size = Number(sizeStr.replace('rem', '')) || 1;
  let bigger = (size * factor).toFixed(1) + 'rem';
  document.body.style.fontSize = bigger;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
<button onclick="resize(1.2)">Bigger</button>
<button onclick="resize(0.8)">Smaller</button>


<h2>H2</h2>
<h3>H3</h3>
<h4>H2</h4>
<p>Paragraph</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way:

```
$root-font-size: 16px;

@function rem($size) {
  @return $size / $root-font-size * 1rem;
}

html {
  font-size: ($root-font-size / 16px) * 100%;
}

.some-block {
  font-size: rem(24px);
}
```

Comment: It looks like this is using a CSS preprocessor. This therefore wouldn't work if a user were trying to change the font size in real time, since preprocessors only **compile to CSS**, and do not run in the browser.

Comment: Yes, this is SCSS. But the same functions can be written in pure CSS.